# Error while setting cross compiler in QT5.2.1

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cross-compiling

I am working on cross compiling QT apps for BeagleBone Black.
I have installed QT5.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and its working perfectly for Ubuntu.
I have installed compiler **gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf 4.8-2013.04-20130417_linux** for cross compilation.

But when I am setting up cross compiler I getting red mark on my kit option and error below :

**The Compiler 'xxxxxxxxx'(arm-linux-generic-elf-32bit) cannot produce code for QT version QT 5.2.1 in PATH QT5 (x86-linux-generic-elf-32bit)**

Screen shot is below:

[image]

I have tried other tool chain also but with no success.
I am unable to understand where I am getting wrong and how to resolve it.

Comment: You should also have a Qt library compiled with that compiler.

Comment: @Nejat Do you know any tool chain for QT 5.2

Comment: I am not aware of any, I think you should get the Qt source code and compile it on your own.